# Codeigniter - Controller named index.php

Tags: php, codeigniter, undefined

A noob question here! I am trying to make an index.php controller to view my site's homepage. But whenever I try to load the controller, I get the following error:

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Index::$load

Filename: controllers/index.php

Line Number: 7

Here is my code:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Index extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('view_index');
    }

}

/* End of file index.php */
/* Location: ./application/controllers/index.php */
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because complete lack of effort: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Message%3A+Undefined+property%3A+Index%3A%3A%24load%27

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include a constructor to your controller:

```
function __construct() {
  parent::__construct();
}
```

Comment: Solved my problem. Thanks! But can you explain how it solved the error?

Comment: $load was initialized when the parent's constructor is called.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have a controller named `Index`, it is said in their documentation on reserved names.

[Reserved Names : CodeIgniter User Guide](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/reserved_names.html)

Best thing to have is a controller named `Home` with `Home.php` as the file name, then put in the configuration of the default controller to have `home`, like so:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'home';
```

Comment: So how do I make my own homepage? I know I can make a controller a default controller. But I don't want the name of the controller appearing when I provide a link to it.